# Python/Numpy: Arrange rows from file into columns in new file

Tags: python, numpy, rows

I have a input file which contains 70 thousand rows: several values (equal number of values for each section, 7 values in that example here) with one headline respectively, like:

```
A
1.13
1.15
1.14
1.11
1.09
1.05
1.02
B
1.03
1.02
1.01
1.00
 .98
 .97
 .97
C
1.02
1.06
1.08
1.10
1.09
1.05
1.00

...
```

Now I'm trying to arrange the sections side by side in columns. It should be like this (there are plenty of columns, only three are shown):

```
Y       E      A
1.13   1.03   1.02
1.15   1.15   1.06  
1.14   1.14   1.08
1.11   1.11   1.10
1.09   1.09   1.09
1.05   1.05   1.05
1.02   1.02   1.00
```

I tried Pandas but there were several problems such as a automatically alphabetic order (A-E-Y columns instead of Y-E-A).
I tried a numpy array, but it failed:

```
import os
import numpy as np


cwd=os.getcwd()

infile=open("mylist.xy","r")
outfile=open("my_columns.xy", "w")

w=infile.read().splitlines()

z = np.array([])
for i in range(0,1000,1):
    z = np.column_stack(z,(np.array(w[5+i*7:12+i*7])))


outfile.write(str(z))
```

The 5+i*7:12+i*7 means, that the first value starts at line 6
I think there must be a much easier way?

Thank you.

Comment: The problem with the alphabetic order is easy to fix. Also, trying a numpy array failed? Too bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read the entire file into a 1D array of strings, then use `reshape` to form a 2D array with the desired columns:

```
arr = np.genfromtxt('data', dtype=None)
arr = arr.reshape(-1, 8).T
```

Use NumPy slicing separate the column names from the data and then use astype to convert the data to floats (and column names to `str`s as opposed to `bytes`):

```
columns = arr[0, :].astype(str)
data = arr[1:].astype(float)
```

Finally, if you wish, you can build a DataFrame out of `data` and `columns`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
arr = np.genfromtxt('data', dtype=None)
arr = arr.reshape(-1, 8).T
columns = arr[0, :].astype(str)
data = arr[1:].astype(float)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
print(df)
```

yields

```
      A     B     C
0  1.13  1.03  1.02
1  1.15  1.02  1.06
2  1.14  1.01  1.08
3  1.11  1.00  1.10
4  1.09  0.98  1.09
5  1.05  0.97  1.05
6  1.02  0.97  1.00
```

---

Alternatively, you could could read the data into a DataFrame using `pd.read_table`,
then use `DataFrame.pivot` to reshape the data as desired:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('data', header=None, names=['val'])
df['column'] = df.index // 8
df['index'] = df.index % 8
df = df.pivot(index='index', columns='column', values='val')
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.iloc[1:].astype(float)
```

yields

```
0         A     B     C
index                  
1      1.13  1.03  1.02
2      1.15  1.02  1.06
3      1.14  1.01  1.08
4      1.11  1.00  1.10
5      1.09  0.98  1.09
6      1.05  0.97  1.05
7      1.02  0.97  1.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option if you don't always have the same number of rows in each output column. This splits the dataframe where ever it finds an uppercase letter (it assumes that these are your headers)

```
import pandas as pd

# read in input file to a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv("mylist.xy", header=None)

# find the indexes of df that begin a new "column"
head_i = df[df[0].str.match('[A-Z]')].index.tolist()

# get tuples corresponding to the boundary indexes of 
# the columns you want to pull out of df

bounds = zip(head_i + head_i[-1:], head_i[1:] + [df.shape[0]+1])

# split df into chunks corresponding to each of the columns
# reset the index for the concatenation step (next)
dfs = [df.loc[start:stop-1].reset_index(drop=True) for start,stop in bounds]

# put them all together
df2 = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)

# set the top row as column headers
df2.columns = df2.iloc[0]
df2.drop(0, inplace=True)

# write to your output file
df2.to_csv("my_columns.xy", index=None)
```